# formal logic proof using a biconditional

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove the following, using natural deduction:
$$p\wedge q\Leftrightarrow p \vdash p \Rightarrow q$$

But I seem to get stuck.  I know I have to prove $q$, but I am not sure if this does it.  Can anyone help me please?  Thank you.

1. $p\wedge q\Leftrightarrow p$ assumption, 0
2. $p\vdash q$ √
   2.1  $p$                  assumption, 2
   2.2  $p\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow I$, 2.1
   2.3  $q\Rightarrow E$, 2.1

Comment: There are many formal proof systems. You need to provide name of the one you are using.

Comment: oh sorry I am a beginner in logic.  It is natural deduction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is not worth keeping; OP is gone and the answer isn't great.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this steps using right natural deduction rules:

Assume p∧q⇔p
From this you can infer $p \implies p \land q$.
To prove $p \implies q$ you assume $p$ this assumption with $p \implies p \land q$ leads to claim that $p \land q$ is true so $q$ is also true. Now you use implication introduction to prove $p \implies q$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/):

[image]

Line 2.2 in the OP's proof is where there appears to be a problem. The assumption of $P$ on line 2.1 should be used to derive $P \land Q$ from the assumption on line 1.

In this proof checker that was done on line 3 using the biconditional elimination (↔E) inference rule.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/