# formal proof with natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Hi I am looking to prove

$r\wedge q\Leftrightarrow r \vdash r\Rightarrow q$

using natural deduction

I get:

- $r\wedge q\Leftrightarrow r$, assumption
- $r\vdash q$
- $r$, assumption

I assume that I also need to formally prove $q$ but cant figure out how to do it(and what rule would I use?)  Am I correct so far?  thank you.

Comment: Is there any typo in $r\wedge q\Leftrightarrow p$? Maybe you meant $r$ instead of $p$? And also, is it $r\wedge (q\Leftrightarrow p)$ or $(r\wedge q)\Leftrightarrow p$?

Comment: yes sorry i have fixed it

Comment: Are you attending same class or have you crated duplicate user to post duplicate post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691161/formal-proof-logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Assume $r$.

Then from the premise $(r\land q) \longleftrightarrow r$, which means $((r\land q)\rightarrow r)\land (r\rightarrow (r\land q))$, we have

(2) $r\rightarrow (r\land q)$,

Since $r$ is assumed, we have, by modus ponens using $(1), (2)$, we have

(3) $r\land q$.

This gives us, from (3),

(4)  $q$.

From the assumption of $r$, we've deduced $q$.

Therefore, $r\rightarrow q$.

Comment: sorry I am still confused how you get to r→(r∧q). is this derived by implication introduction?  To do this do you not have to prove (r∧q) on its own?

Comment: @user131673 It's $\to \text{elimination}$ that is used.

Comment: Actually, we use biconditional elimination in defining $(r\land q)\iff r$ to be the conjunction of two implications, $((r\land q)\rightarrow r)\land (r\rightarrow (r\land q))$, and then use "and"-elimination to get the implication we want: $r\rightarrow (r\land q).$ With $r$ as an assumption then, by using $\rightarrow$-elimination, we get $r\land q$...

Comment: thank you very much.  apologies again, i am thick with a capital T.  I worked this out.  is this also valid:                     1. p∧q⇔p assumption
2. r⇒r∧q,⇔Elimination, 1
3. r turnstile p∧q √
3.1 r,  assumption, 3
3.2 r, ∧Elimination,3
3.3 r⇒q, ⇒Introduction. 3.1,3.2

Comment: thank you again, you have been a big help

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!